# tkinter: change cursor size

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

In tkinter python library with the line

```
self.canvas.config(cursor="hand1")
```

I can change the cursor inside the canvas. However, it results different in different operative system, especially in windows the cursors look like smaller respect to linux systems. Is there a way to change the cursor dimensions?

Comment: i was wondering if u had .cur file of it with a larger size and then use it? as cursor? like `canvas.config(cursor=@file_name.cur)`

Comment: I don't know if tkinter admits persolized cursors..

Comment: yep it does with the syntax i gav

Comment: i get invalid sintax error ..

Comment: oh u pass it as a string like `canvas.config(cursor='@file_name.cur')`, my bad

Comment: I already tried, but no results. I also tried giving the full pth of the .cur file but it still get me error. Maybe the problem is tkinter for linux?

Comment: dont knw abt dat but works alright for me with windows